# URL rewrite like instagram profile

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite my URLs with unique slug like Instagram or Facebook.

Example: facebook.com/joe

My URLs are like that: `website.com/user.php?username=joe`

I try this rule in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ user.php?username=$1 [L]
```

But it doesn't work, it redirects on `/user.php`.

It works if I use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^u/([^/]*)$ /user.php?username=$1 [L]
```

But result is `website.com/u/joe` and I prefer without `u`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `.htaccess` in your web root `/` directory

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ user.php?username=$1 [NC,L]
```

The `.*` in the pattern `^(.*)$` matches `/anything` and the parentheses help capture the **anything** part as a `$1` variable used in the substitution URL as `user.php?username=$1`.

In case if you need multiple parameters you can simply add `&%{QUERY_STRING}` after `$1` to separate and add them to the end of your query string.
for example :  if you pass `website.com/joe?age=31` the result will be `website.com/user.php?username=joe&age=31`.

Finally, the flag `NC` simply makes the rule non case-sensitive, so it matches `/Joe` or `/JOE` as well.